# Bounds on the probability of getting exactly one head.

Tags: probability, inequality

Consider $d$ coins tossed independently with the probability of getting a head for each one being $2^{-x}$ with $x \in \mathbb{Z}^+$. Further let $\frac{1}{4d} \leq \frac{1}{2^x} < \frac{1}{2d}$.  This in fact enough to constrain $x$ to be one value for each $d$.

I am trying to work out a lower bound for the probability that there is exactly one head.

---

If $p = 2^{-x}$ then the probability of getting exactly one head is $d\cdot p\cdot (1-p)^{d-1}$.  But I am not sure where to go from there.

Numerically it seems that $0.19536805881862096$... is a lower bound  for the probability but I don't know how to prove it. (Edited lower bound following given answer.)

Comment: By basic properties of the binomial distribution, the probability of getting exactly $k$ heads is $\binom dk \times p^k\times (1-p)^{d-k}$.

Comment: So you are given upper and lower bounds on $p$. Use this to get upper and lower bounds on $1-p$. From this get upper and lower bounds on $(1-p)^{d-1}$. Combine those results to get upper and lower bounds on the probability.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By Bernoulli's inequality, $(1-p)^{d-1}\geq 1-(d-1)p\geq 1-dp$. Therefore $dp(1-p)^{d-1}\geq dp-(dp)^2$. Now $dp\in[1/4,1/2)$ by assumption, and the function $f(x)=x-x^2$ is increasing in the region $[1/4,1/2)$, so a lower bound is $f(1/4)=3/16=0.1875$.

You can presumably do a little better than this using a better approximation than Bernoulli's inequality, but not as well as your claimed bound. For $d=64$ the probability is about $0.195368$.

Comment: Thank you! What might a better approximation be?

Comment: Curiously if we change $p$ to be bounded between $1/2$ and $1$ we get $0$ as the lower bound even though in reality the lower bound should be higher. Is there an easy way to fix this?

Comment: @fornin did you mean if $dp$ is between $1/2$ and $1$? I think you can fix that using the fact that $(1-1/d)^{d-1}>1/e$ for $d\geq 2$; since $1-p\geq 1-1/d$ this gives a lower bound of $1/(2e)$.